# go install in Dockerfile "could not read Username for 'https://github.com'"

Tags: linux, golang, docker, devops, dockerfile

Пытаюсь сделать Docker image (container) из папки на моем компьютере с ОС Linux-mint (к git не обращаюсь) и получаю устойчивую ошибку

[image]

> exit status 128:     fatal: could not read Username for
> 'https://github.com': terminal prompts disabled Confirm the import
> path was entered correctly. If this is a private repository, see
> https://golang.org/doc/faq#git_https for additional information.

*причем ссылка в тексте ошибки ссылается на документацию к go get*

Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.17.1

ADD . /home/mintuser/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server

RUN go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server@latest

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/server"]

EXPOSE 5300
```

[SSH правка конфига git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59797272/receiving-fatal-could-not-read-username-for-https-github-com-terminal-prom) не дает изменений. Благодарен, если подскажете куда копать!

```
git config --global url.ssh://git@github.com/.insteadOf https://github.com/
```

Comment: Я прошу прощения, а разве в строке докерфайла "RUN go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server@latest" Вы не обращаетесь в явном виде к гитхабу?

Comment: Меня это тоже смущает, но код взят из примера. И чтобы скачать с гита зачем ему мой ник? Курение документации не помогает: Команда go install ведет себя почти идентично go build, но вместо того чтобы оставлять исполняемый файл в текущей директории или директории, отмеченной флагом -o, она помещает исполняемый файл в директорию $GOPATH/bin.

Comment: ну на скриншоте ошибка появляется именно после этой строки

Comment: Есть идея: у Вас команда docker build работает из под sudo. Значит, настройки текущего пользователя при работе этой команды не используются. Ну, если там авторизация на гите по ключам была настроена ит.п. Попробуйте просто в консоли выполнить команду "go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server@latest" из под sudo и посмотрите, будет ли ошибка?

Comment: Может, если docker build делат то, что Вам нужно и выполняется без ошибок, эту команду и вставить в докерфайл?

Comment: Исправил $GOBIN! go install -v ./server/ ставит куда нужно без ошибок! Докер по прежнему ругается на Username

Comment: а ссылку на пример добавить вы можете? , т.к.  у github.com/EwRvp7LV7 аккаунта нет таких репозиториев, вы точно правильно скопировали, или возможно человек уже удалил пример

Comment: @ExplodingKitten пример отсюда habr.com/ru/post/461279

Comment: я не разработчик `go`, но гайд правильный, если вы используете go 1.12 и пофиксите пути (вы зачем-то указала `/home/mintuser`, то все будет работать

Comment: @ExplodingKitten Поменял на go 1.12, путь правильный (на /go/... не находит), теперь другая ошибка 
Step 2/5 : ADD . /home/mintuser/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server
 ---> Using cache
 ---> b1e249f12774
Step 3/5 : RUN go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server
 ---> Running in 08951d49d4cd
can't load package: package github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server: cannot find package "github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server" in any of:
 /usr/local/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server (from $GOROOT)
 **/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server** (from $GOPATH)

Comment: Такого репозитория нет по этому адресу - https://github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server,  сначала нужно решить это проблему.

Comment: @JohnNix а с чего вы взяли что он правильный, если что это не путь на вашей системе, а путь в контейнере, а там нет никакого mintuser пользователя

Answer (score 0):

Всё понятно.

Смотрите.

Команда на построение образа должна быть `sudo docker build -t myimagename .`

Здесь myimagename - это имя образа в той системе, где docker build его построит. Хотите - замените его в команде, котрую будете набирать, на что то более осмысленное. Потом команда `docker images` Вам его покажет в списке имиджей.

А ошибка с именем пользователя может возникнуть только по той причине, которую Вам указали в комментариях: нет такого репозитория на гитхабе. Вполне возможно, он когда то был, но его удалили. Или переименовали.

Поэтому Вам надо научиться строить Ваш образ без обращения к гитахбу. Ну, или обращаться к существующему репозиторию.

Кстати, на скриншоте видно, какая именно команда в Dockerfile вызывает ошибку.

Comment: Да, из примера. sudo docker build . выдает ту же ошибку. Я пробовал вместо matzhouse писать свой ник от гитхаба, не помогает. Докер еще ругается, что все буквы должн быть в нижнем регистре. Но насколько понимаю matz...server это просто название image. Или докер в любом варианте требует все сгружать ему на хаб?

Comment: При этом он все таки ругается на go install и имя гитхаба! 
The command '/bin/sh -c go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server@latest' returned a non-zero code: 1

Comment: У вас смешиваются два типа ошибок: 1)ошибки, допущенные в докерфайле и 2) ошибки, допущенные в консольной команде `docker build .` Давайте сначала сделаем докерфайл, КАЖДАЯ из команд в котором выполняется без ошибок, если её взять и выполнить в консоли. Потом выполним команду `docker build .` без каких либо ключей и параметров (она построит образ локально). Должно помочь!

Answer (score 0):

доступ к приватным репозиториям лучше организовать через GitHub Personal Token. Зайдите в настройки пользователя, создайте новый персональный токен PAT, переедайте его во время сборки

`docker build --build-arg GITHUB_TOKEN=<you token here> -t my_image_name .`

```
FROM golang:1.17.1

# use GITHUB_TOKEN token for fetch private modules
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN

RUN git config \
  --global \
  url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf \
  "https://github.com"
ADD . /home/mintuser/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server

RUN go install -v github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server@latest

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/server"]

EXPOSE 5300
```

но проблема совсем в другом.

Исходя из строки `ADD . /home/mintuser/go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server` я могу сделать вывод. что вы уже написали код, и этот код хотите копировать уже внутрь контейнера для сборки. тогда вам нужно сбилдить ваш код после копирования следующим образом

```
FROM golang:1.17.1

# use GITHUB_TOKEN token for fetch private modules
ARG GITHUB_TOKEN

RUN git config \
  --global \
  url."https://${GITHUB_TOKEN}@github.com".insteadOf \
  "https://github.com"

COPY ./ ./

RUN go mod download

RUN go build -o /app main.go

ENTRYPOINT ["/app"]

EXPOSE 5300
```

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем! Магия оказалась в /go/src/, WORKDIR и go.mod.

Что нужно запустить:

```
github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server/main.go
```

Создаем go.mod с зависимостями в ./grpctest:

```
$ export GO111MODULE="auto" && go mod init && go mod tidy
```

Там же Dockerfile

```
FROM golang:1.17

#ADD не рекомендуют
#копируем все файлы из текущей папки в /go
COPY . /go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest

#из этой папки запускаются executable, хотя не обязательно в ней находятся
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest

#full path! Оба варианта рабочие
#The -v flag prints the names of packages and files as they are processed. 
#RUN go install -v /go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server/main.go
RUN go install -v /go/src/github.com/EwRvp7LV7/grpctest/server

#go build помещает результат в любую папку, go install в $GOBIN, в остальном разницы не заметил.
ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/main"]

EXPOSE 5300
```

Dockerfile v2. Длинный path не обязателен:

```
FROM golang:1.17

COPY . /go/src
WORKDIR /go/src/app

RUN go install -v /go/src/server

ENTRYPOINT ["/go/bin/main"]

EXPOSE 5300
```

Запускаем:

```
sudo docker build .
```

В последней строке забираем ID image:

```
Successfully built f4435bb4730e
```

Bingo!